# ipa app could not added to our itunes library, it is not a valid app

Tags: ios, swift, unsigned

I have made an unsigned .IPA app using xcode 6 and swift language.
I have compressed the .app file and change its extention to .ipa.
When I want to install this .ipa file on my jailbreaked iPhone, this error is appeard:
"the app 'youtapp.ipa' could not be added to your iTunes library because it is not a valid app".
Would you please let me know what the problem is.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was using the "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" option from Organizer to create an ipa file. It appears however that this is broken in XCode 6. Your answer from Jan 1 got me thinking so I did a little digging.

I renamed the exported ipa file to .zip and opened her up. XCode is now putting the .app file inside a folder named "Applications". So I went ahead and renamed this folder to "Payload", zipped it back up, and renamed the zip back to .ipa. Sure enough when I dragged this new ipa file to iTunes it works fine and can be installed on my phone.

Seems to me a bug in XCode, I think I should report it to Apple.

Comment: I spent days trying to figure out why my Ad Hoc stopped installing, indeed there is Application folder in .ipa instead of Payload. WTF Apple?

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact same problem using Xcode 6.3 when building my iOS app. It seems that the packager does not complain when the following setting is enabled even though the target is an iOS device:

```
Application requires iPhone environment:NO
```

You need to set the this to `YES` and it will name the folder correctly to `Payload`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, unfortunately posted late.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to create an .ipa for adHoc distribution for one of the Old project (built a year ago by ex-developer). After a lot of research in google and following this link - [here](https://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/tag/app-could-not-be-added-to-your-itunes-library-because-it-is-not-a-valid-app/ps://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/tag/app-could-not-be-added-to-your-itunes-library-because-it-is-not-a-valid-app/). By replacing the .plist file with the existing working projects (obviously - the relevant icons/bundle display name/identifier) and renaming with the current .plist name. It worked for me.

I literally spent about 3-4 hours to fix this issue. Hope it helps some one.

environment was native - iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I forgot to put the .app file in the Payload folder. After putting the .app file in to the Payload Folder, I zip the folder and change its extension to .ipa.
It works correctly.