# The app could not be added to your itunes library because it is not a valid app

Tags: ios, xcode

My app is already in itunes and after some changes on the existing app,I created the new app id ,certificates and provisioning profiles and then generated .ipa file using folowing steps...

1. Go to Product-->Archive
   2.Click on Export option.
   .ipa file was generated but when opening with itunes it displayed error as...
   "The app could not be added to your itunes library because it is not a valid app".

What this error means..??I only want to to generate ipa file using adhoc distribution so that the app can be tested on number of devices .

What should I do..??

My existing app has version and build as 2.1.2 but now I changed to as 2.5,then also its displaying error...
Please help if anyone can.....Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: That's because the the app which is already there in iTunes should be "updated" with its previous app id only. Do not change the app id and its respective mobileprovision. Just update and release a new "version"

Comment: Actually,the distribution certificate which was used earlier has been expired so I created a new app id,certificates and adhoc profile but then to its displaying error

Comment: Then you should have revoked the same certificate and used the same one. Do not change it.

Comment: Also, I am sure that you have validate option when you archive

Comment: I also tried doing this ...I revoked the certificate,then I created new certificate with the same bundle id..then also same error occurs..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue from the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398473/ipa-app-could-not-added-to-our-itunes-library-it-is-not-a-valid-app):

In order to resolve this issue, do these steps:

Renamed the exported ipa file to .zip and opened her up.
XCode is now putting the .app file inside a folder named "Applications".
Rename this folder to "Payload", zipped it back up, and rename the zip back to .ipa.
Now dragged this new ipa file to iTunes it should works fine this time and can be installed on my phone.

This seems a bug in Xcode in latest Xcode versions.

Comment: In my case the issue was due to an empty build field. The extracted directory was already called `Payload`

Comment: @mnVoh Great catch! Thanks!